# Show only folder name with the link information via Windows DIR

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

How can I get only folder and its symbolic link information output via `dir`?

- What I want is this, where `CNET` and `projects` are symbolic links:

  ```
  CNET [\\192.168.1.10\CNET]
  elements
  localized
  projects [\\192.168.1.10\CNET\homes\andi\projects]
  render
  ```

If I do:

```
$ dir z:

     Directory of Z:\

    09/12/2023  17:25    <DIR>          .
    08/12/2023  00:16    <DIR>          ..
    09/12/2023  17:25    <SYMLINKD>     CNET [\\192.168.1.10\CNET]
    08/12/2023  01:07    <DIR>          elements
    08/12/2023  02:26    <DIR>          localized
    09/12/2023  17:25    <SYMLINKD>     projects [\\192.168.1.10\CNET\homes\andi\projects]
    08/12/2023  02:26    <DIR>          render
                   0 File(s)              0 bytes
                   7 Dir(s)  346.504.175.616 bytes free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Use a `for /f` loop and configure the tokens with `"tokens=4,5,*"`.
- Insert the command `'dir /AL ^| findstr 192'` within single quotes into the loop's command section.
- Then, use `echo %%~A %%~B %%~C` to display the desired output.

This structure allows you to process the output of the specified command, with `%%~A, %%~B, and %%~C` representing the relevant tokens in each iteration getting the desired output for applicable values.

### Batch

> **Note:** This is the format to run as a batch script.

```
for /f "tokens=4,5,*" %%A in ('dir /AL ^| findstr 192') do (echo %%~A %%~B %%~C)
```

### Command Line

> **Note:** This is the format to run from command line.

```
for /f "tokens=4,5,*" %A in ('dir /AL ^| findstr 192') do (echo %~A %~B %~C)
```

#### Supporting Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- `FOR /?`

  > ```
  > FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]
  >
  >
  >     delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
  >                       default delimiter set of space and tab.
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  >
  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  > enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  > ```
- `Findstr /?`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This is perfect ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The help for the `dir` command shows the following:

```
C:\>dir /?
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             O  Offline files
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
.
.
.
```

Use the `/b` option to show only the names (no other details) and `/al` switch to show reparse points (symbolic links and junctions) or `/adl`

```
dir /b /al
```

or

```
dir /b /adl
```

Comment: I'm using windows 11 and it doesn't work. Using dir /b /al or dir /b /adl didn't give me the the link. I ony see the filename. what's wrong ? I only got 'CLAYNET' and 'projects' without any link information.

Comment: @andio What about 'dir /b /ad'? "... without any link information", that's what the output you requested on your question, that's why `/b` is used to prevent showing information.

Comment: 'dir /b /ad'  showing all the files , but still no symlink inforrmation. I want the link information to be displayed. For example : CNET [\\192.168.1.10\CNET] , not just CNET

Comment: any update on this one ?